# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не включается музыка?

Tags: python

У меня не включается музыка в чем проблема???

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import os

from playsound import playsound

from threading import Thread


root = Tk()

Image = Image.open("image_.jpg")

Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image)

panel = Label(root, image = Image)

panel.pack()

T = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=32)

T.pack()

T.insert(tk.END,"Король и шут - Дурак и Молния...")

Thread(target=playsound, args=('"audio.mp3"',)).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не запустили поток. Используйте этот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
from playsound import playsound
from threading import Thread

root = Tk()

Image = Image.open("image_.jpg")
Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image)

panel = Label(root, image = Image)
panel.pack()

T = Text(root, height=1, width=32)
T.pack()
T.insert(END,"Король и шут - Дурак и Молния...")

th1 = Thread(target=lambda: playsound('audio.mp3'))
th1.start()

root.mainloop()
th1.join()
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручил!!!